Conditional Index value replacement based on the presence of a specific Index value
suppose to have the following:

data DB;
  input ID :$20.Date :date9. Index;
  format Date date9.;
cards;
0001 06DEC2016   0
0001 08NOV2020   1
0004 14MAY2015   0
0004 30JUN2015   0
0004 16FEB2019   0
0005 10AUG2019   1
0006 10SEP2014   0
0006 01NOV2015   0
0006 10AUG2021   1
....
;


Is there a way to get the following?

data DB1;
  input ID :$20.Date :date9. Index;
  format Date date9.;
cards;
0001 06DEC2016   1
0001 08NOV2020   1
0004 14MAY2015   0
0004 30JUN2015   0
0004 16FEB2019   0
0005 10AUG2019   1
0006 10SEP2014   1
0006 01NOV2015   1
0006 10AUG2021   1
....
;


In other words: if there is at least one "1" in the column Index for an ID, all the values in the column Index should be converted from 0 to 1, for that ID (like for ID 0001) otherwise nothing (ID 0004 has only 0s in the column Index in DB so nothing happens).
Thank you in advance,
Best

I'm not an expert SAS so i'm not suggesting code but it seems you need a subquery. I suggest you to use PROC SQL and do a subquery for the index column where you select rows with same id and index 1, if found return 1 else 0

Since it's already in order by ID, you can do a basic self-merge: one on the full table, and one on the subset where index=1. If there's a match between IDs, set index to 1. Otherwise, it's 0.
data want;
    merge db(in=t1)
          db(in=t2 where=(index=1));
    by id;

    index = (t1=t2);
run;

If you don't want to worry about variable order and you want to do it all in one step, you have two options: SQL and a hash table.
With SQL, it looks like this:
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select t1.ID
             , t1.Date
             , (t1.id=t2.id) as index
        from db as t1
        LEFT JOIN
             db(where=(index=1)) as t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id
    ;
quit;

With a hash table, it looks like this:
data want;
    set db;

    if(_N_ = 1) then do;
        dcl hash lookup(dataset: 'db(where=(index=1))');
            lookup.defineKey('id');
        lookup.defineDone();
    end;

    /* Return code is 0 if there is a match */
    index = (lookup.Check()=0);
run;

ID      Date        Index
0001    06DEC2016   1
0001    08NOV2020   1
0004    14MAY2015   0
0004    30JUN2015   0
0004    16FEB2019   0
0005    10AUG2019   1
0006    10SEP2014   1
0006    01NOV2015   1
0006    10AUG2021   1

